# How to insert var into type in method

Tags: c#, variables, types, type-conversion

I'm using a method to repeat the code for opening a new form and I want to use a method so when I select a button it'll open the corresponding form.
So when the button is clicked my var will change and I will pass that into the method to change which form is opened.
I have all the code for button clicking and opening the new form sorted just neither my friends or I can think of how to do it.

```
private void OPENCUSTOMER(object sender, EventArgs e, string FormName)
    {
        this.Hide();
        var CUSTOMERFORM = new CUSTOMERFORM();
        CUSTOMERFORM.Show();
    }
```

instead of repeating the code for opening a new form I thought I could use the method. But I don't know to format it so I can have a string I can change for every click and insert that into the method.

```
private void OPENCUSTOMER(object sender, EventArgs e, string FormName,string FormName)
    {
        FormName="CUSTOMERTABLE";
        OpenNewForm(FormName)
    }
public static OpenNewForm(string NewForm)
    {
        this.Hide();
        var NewForm = new NewForm();
        NewForm.Show();
    }
```

I'm using a method to repeat the code for opening a new form and I want to use a method so when I select a button it'll open the corresponding form.
So when the button is clicked my var will change and I will pass that into the method to change which form is opened.
I have all the code for button clicking and opening the new form sorted just neither my friends or I can think of how to do it.

Comment: you should show what it is you have so far, do not post questions in this nature without having something code wise to support what you have and or have tried, this will lead to potential downvoting or question being closed , edit the original question and post what you have ..

Comment: Also after reading your question, this is actually pretty simple to do, are you familiar with Button Click Events , or switch(){ case: } statements, or how to create an instance of a forms class that you want to show..? once again show what you have and others can properly guide you as well as lend advice

Comment: I'm not trying to instantiate anything I'm just trying to cut down the repeated code. Pretty much all I had coded was the method and the calling of the method. Ill edit it now.

Comment: so ..you expect us to know what method you coded..? show what you have coded this is not rocket science..

Comment: sorry man I just wanted to know if it was possible I thought it was easy enough to understand what I was trying to accomplish I'll add it now

Comment: anything is possible in code if you know what you want and you know what you are doing..

Comment: I'm still fairly new to coding so don't assume I know what I'm doing all that well :)

Comment: I would suggest reading some C# basics, tutorials also focus on how to create instances of Forms / Classes, pay attention to naming conventions too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dylan says you could do this with reflection but that's probably a bit advanced as you've said you're still fairly new at coding. The issue you have is that the name of the form.

```
string NewForm
```

Does not equate to the actual object that is a form. Think of the string as a name of a car; by someone giving you a piece of card with that name on you don't have the car. Neither by knowing the name of the car can you create that car. So the line:

```
var NewForm = new NewForm();
```

Won't work (as you've already declared NewForm as a string)

It's admirable trying to minimise code and code repetition but in this case I'd personally leave it and have the two or three lines of code you need for each button to open the applicable form (but do keep looking to minimise code in other areas). Hope that's of use.

Answer (score 0):

If you really did have a genuine need to implement `public static OpenNewForm(string NewForm)`, where `NewForm` was the class name of the form, it could be done using reflection - but you'd have a have a very good reason for wanting to this. I'd suggest you declare it instead `OpenNewForm<T>(T form) where T : Form`, and call it with `OpenNewForm<CustomerForm>`().